# How to create a link to make it "write to a specific Gmail"?

Tags: hyperlink, gmail

I'm trying to make a footer, with Instagram link, Facebook link, Youtube link so on and so forth. My question is: How do I create a link that specifically refers to a state like write to an email account?

For instance, I have this email:

```
example@gmail.com
```

What I want is a link like this:

```
https://mail.google.com/write_to:example@gmail.com
```

And when someone clicks on it, the Gmail automatyli opens the "write letter tab" to example@gmail.com.

Thanks :)

Comment: Dupe of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8852679

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't force somebody to gmail. You can use a normal link

```
<a href='mailto:example@gmail.com?subject=write letter>mail to</a>
```

This will open the users default mail app.

Details can be found at http://tutorialspark.com/html5/HTML5_email_mailto.php

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Opera, and it opens a new tab in chrome

Comment: A new empty tab

Comment: I tryed in chrome and same result.

Comment: Did you check if you set your mail client properly. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/34413697/229864

Comment: I chechked out, but it's still does not work for me.